# Two CSS media queries Override each other

Tags: css, media-queries

I have 2 media queries as below!

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
  .rightlist{
    margin-top: 0px !important;
  }

}


@media (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 801px){
  .rightlist{
    margin-top: -10px !important;
 }

}
```

When both media queries together the above query is overriding the below one. Is there someone who know the fix for this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle.net link of your content

Comment: yes. agree with bolt..both media queries are for different resolution. Post live or demo so we can try to find the main cause.

Comment: I have added a media query to zoom out list li content to a lower value below 800px! I'll add jsfiddle if  possible because I'm working on a cakephp project in server.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this , this css will be applied for screen up to 1000px but as soon as you will hit 800px your previous media query will be apply

```
@media (max-width: 1000px){
  .rightlist{
     margin-top: -10px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: well what is the difference the op's media queries and yours? please give little bit more info that hows your query is different.

Comment: I have zoomed out the li elements to a lower value below 800px in another media query. I added this code but still below 800px I have same alignment issue. I need to get it back to margin 0 below 800px

Comment: can you paste all you code on jsfiddle.net or codepen.io and share the link

Comment: ok Ill try it, because Im working on a cakephp site on server and my job is redesigning it's interface and integrate new design to old site! so I may need some time for that!